# Array type expected; found int

Tags: java, android

I'm receiving this error "Array type expected, found int" in my code and I don't know why and where is the trouble.
Can somebody help me?
This is my code:

```
private float curX = 0, curY = 0, curZ = 0;
static float acel;
static int cont=0;   
static int tamanio = 1200; 
static int int_buffer=tamanio;

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    curX = event.values[0];
    curY = event.values[1];
    curZ = event.values[2];

    acel = curX * curX + curY * curY + curZ * curZ;
    int acel2 = Math.round(acel);

    //I RECIVE THE ERROR HERE:
    int_buffer[cont]=acel2;

    //AND HERE TOO
    if(int_buffer[cont]>max){
        max=int_buffer[cont];
    }
    if(int_buffer[cont]<min){
        min=int_buffer[cont];
    }
}
```

Comment: You are declaring int but reffer to it as an array.

Comment: how can i declarate int_buffer as an array of int?

Comment: you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-do-i-declare-and-initialize-an-array-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You declare int_buffer as an integer, try

```
int[] int_buffer = new int[tamanio];
```